# Why onActivityResult() called before uploading to Flickr finishes using Flickrj-android

Tags: android, android-intent, flickr, onactivityresult, flickrj

I need to do a feature like this for my app: when user presses a "Save" button, the selected image will be uploaded to Flickr, and then getting the source of uploaded image from Flickr to store into database. I use flickrj-android library to do. This is my code:

```
//call this function when "Save" button is clicked
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FlickrjActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("flickImagePath", currentScreenshot);   
startActivityForResult(intent, UPLOAD_FLICKR);
Log.i("ordering","afterStartFlickrUpload");
```

onActivityResult()

```
switch(requestCode){
   case UPLOAD_FLICKR:
         Log.i("ordering","beforeResultCode");
         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){   
             String flickr_source = data.getStringExtra("flickr_source");
             Log.i("flickr",flickr_source);
         }
         break;
}
```

And I have an Activity called FlickrjActivity which creates an AsyncTask called UploadPhotoTask
UploadPhotoTask has a method called onPostExecute which has a parameter which is the Flickr photo ID of uploaded photo as a response from Flickr API

```
protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
   Log.i("photoID",response);
}
```

This is load() method of the FlickrjActivity:

```
private void load(OAuth oauth) {
    if (oauth != null) {

        UploadPhotoTask taskUpload = new UploadPhotoTask(this, new File(
                path));
        taskUpload.setOnUploadDone(new UploadPhotoTask.onUploadDone() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("flickr_source", "This is a link");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        taskUpload.execute(oauth);
    }
}
```

My expected process is the main activity creates an intent which calls `FlickrjActivity`, which will create `UploadPhotoTask` to upload the photo to Flickr, get the photoID and then returns this ID to main activity using `setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);` and `finish();`

But right after I press the Save button, the `onActivityResult()` called since `Log.i("ordering","beforeResultCode");` prints message to Logcat before uploading runs, so the block inside `if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)` never been called since `onActivityResult()` won't be called again after uploading completes. So why `onActivityResult()` be called before `finish()` of `FlickrjActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

I did find the answer, just need to change android:launchMode from "singleTask" to "singleTop", although I don't know why.